C# Quartz удаление объекта джобы
Я использую Quartz в связке с Dependecy Injection. У меня есть несколько джоб, настроенных через RepeatForever(), требующие сервисы типа Transient от DI. Я обнаружил, что объекты моих IJob не удаляются после выполнения, и висят где-то в памяти вместе со всеми полученными сервисами из DI, из-за чего утекает память. Как заставить удаляться инстансы джоб после выполнения?
public class JobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public JobFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType) as IJob;
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
        
    }
}


"объекты моих IJob не удаляются после выполнения" - можно поподробнее, пожалуйста?

Я реализовал JobFactory и прокинул все джобы в DI. Метод ReturnJob интерфейса IJobFactory я не реализовывал и не совсем понимаю, что там должно быть. По итогу джобы создаются, выполняются, выглядит так, как будто все в порядке, но на практике происходит утечка памяти. Проверил профайлером - в памяти остаются объекты сервисов, сборщик их не собирает. Судя по всему из-за того что осстаются объекты выполненных джоб и хранят ссылки на сервисы, вот GC их и игнорирует

приведите, пожалуйста, код самой фабрики

Проект на гитхабе, вот файл с фабрикой https://github.com/scrzii/StatisticsBot/blob/master/StatisticsBot/Jobs/JobFactory.cs

тут всего 20 строк кода, по-этому, пожалуйста добавьте сам код в вопрос. Что на счёт ReturnJob - то, как я понимаю, это метод который позволяет вам обработать некую работу, которая уже была выполнена. Если бы вы хотели реализовать какой-то пул работ, то на этом этапе вы бы возвращали работу в пул. Так как пул вы не реализовываете, то просто вызывайте job.Dispose() внутри ReturnJob и у вас не будет утечек памяти

Так мои джобы не реализуют метод Dispose, я не понимаю, что именно я там должен финализировать

Проблема оказалась в том, что DI не завершает по дефолту IDisposable сервисы если они объявлены в виде Transient. Поэтому нужно создавать пространство IServiceScope, создавать сервисы в нем и после этого вызывать Dispose этого самого пространства. Решил проблему так:
public class JobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly Dictionary<IJob, IServiceScope> _jobScopeMapping = new();

    public JobFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var job = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(bundle.JobDetail.JobType) as IJob;
        _jobScopeMapping.Add(job, scope);

        return job;
    }

    public void ReturnJob(IJob job)
    {
        if (!_jobScopeMapping.TryGetValue(job, out var scope))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mapping for job does not found!");  // Ну здесь, конечно, логгер должен быть
            return;
        }

        _jobScopeMapping.Remove(job);
        scope.Dispose();
    }
}

